# Why does a mongodb replica set need an odd number of voting members?

Tags: mongodb

If find the replica set requirement a bit confusing, and I'm probably missing something obvious (like under which condition there are elections).

I understand that in normal operations you need quorum, and a voting takes place and to get a majority you need and odd numbers of machines.

But since we use a replica set for failover, if the master dies, then we are left with an even number of voting members, which based on my limited experience lengthen the time to elect a primary.

Also according to the documentation, the addition of a voting member doesn't start an election, it would seem that starting (booting) you replica set with an even number of nodes would make more sense?

So if we start say with 4 machines in the replica set, and one machine dies, there is a re-election with 3 machines, fast quorum. We add a machine back to get back to our normal operation state, no re-election and we are back to our normal operation conditions.

Can someone shed a light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: With single master systems, even partitions make it impossible to determine which remainder still has a majority, taking both systems down.

Let N be a cluster of four machines:

- One machine dies, the others resume operation. Good.
- Two machines die, we're offline because we no longer get a majority. Bad.

Let M be a cluster of three machines:

- One machine dies, the others resume operation. Good.
- Two machines die, we're offline because we no longer get a majority. Bad.

**=> Same result at 3/4 of the cost.**

Now, let's add an assumption or two:

- We're also going to operate some kind of server application that *uses* the database
- The network can be partitioned

Let's say you have two datacenters, one with two database instances and the backend server machines. If the connection to the backup center (which has one MongoDB instance) fails, you're still online.

Now if you added a second MongoDB instance at the backup data center, a network partition would, despite seemingly higher redundancy, yield *lower* availability since we'd lose the majority in case of a network partition and can't continue to operate.

**=> *Less* availability at higher cost. But that doesn't answer the question yet.**

Let's say you're really worried about availability: You have two data centers, with backend servers in *both* datacenters, anycast IPs, the whole deal. Now the network between the two DCs is partitioned, but some clients connect to DC A while other reach DC B. How do you now determine which datacenter may accept writes? It's not possible - this is why the odd number is *necessary*.

You don't actually need Anycast IPs, BGP or any fancy stuff for the problem to become real, any writing application (like a worker, a stale request, anything) would require later *merging* different writes, which is a completely different concurrency scheme.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your example with 3 and 4 machines. In the case that we start with 4 machines if two die (so we are left with 2), you say it's bad. In the case we start with 3 machines one die (so we are also left with 2), you say it's good. Is it the case that the vote takes into consideration every node, even those who cannot participate in the vote anymore?

Comment: With 3 machines, the system remains up if one machine goes down, but not 2. With 4 machines, it's the same, because 2/4 is not a majority, so it can't elect a master, so there's no advantage to the additional machine, but there's additional cost. The more interesting problems are network partitions, however, but there the same applies: if the network splits the machines in two two-machine sets, you're *worse* off, because even with all machines running, none can accept a write.

Comment: Ah, you edited your comment. Yes, 2/3 is a majority, 2/4 is not a majority. More to the point: think of a network partition: all nodes can 'take part in the vote', but the other half can't see that. Since you can't distinguish node failures from partitions, you must always choose the majority of all voting members, not just the ones that are available (cat biting tail)

Comment: now that make sense, but then if you are going to perform maintenance on one machine, and you are going to remove it from the replica set first, wouldn't that imply that you are better of stating with 4 machines then?

Comment: If your machines are so prone to error or require so long maintenance intervals, I'd rather worry about that. In any case, no: four machines are *less* resilient to partitions. If you're so worried about the cluster being up, simply use 5 members.